# jquery ui dialog titlebar behaving erratically

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have a pretty standard HTML page that I'm trying to use the jQuery UI's dialog box on. I've used this dialog lots before and usually it couldn't be simpler. However, for some reason, I'm now having a problem where calling the dialog on `<div id="upload_only_dialog"></div>` while displaying the dialog, is

1.making the titlebar of the dialog about 700px tall and

2.applying the style [moderizer.js .placeholder](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text) to all the text within the dialog

I don't know what's going on with the placeholder styles being applied to the dialog (light gray text for everything), but what is really confusing is the titlebar. I've narrowed down the problematic HTML to this section of my document. When I remove it, the titlebar is the appropriate size. When I replace it, it is uncannily oversize. It seems totally innocuous. Here it is:

```
<div class="triple_col_container secondary_panel" style="display:block">
    <div class="trip_col secondary_panel_copy">
        <p class="trip_col">
            Get in touch with us to get your project rolling!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary_panel_content_wrapper">
        <div class="col_header secondary_panel_header">
            <h2 class="columns">
                Question or comment?
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary_panel_col1">
            <p class="secondary_panel_label">
                First name:
                <span class="required_ast">
                    *
                </span>
            </p>
            <div class="secondary_panel_input_container">
                <input type="text" id="mail_first_name_input" class="secondary_panel_input pr"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary_panel_col2">
            <p class="secondary_panel_label">
                Last name:
                <span class="required_ast">
                    *
                </span>
            </p>
            <div class="secondary_panel_input_container">
                <input type="text" id="mail_last_name_input" class="secondary_panel_input pr"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tbc">
        </div>
        <div class="secondary_panel_col1">
            <p class="secondary_panel_label">
                Company name:
            </p>
            <div class="secondary_panel_input_container">
                <input type="text" id="mail_company_name_input" class="secondary_panel_input secondary_panel_long_input"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tbc">
        </div>
        <div class="secondary_panel_col1">
            <p class="secondary_panel_label">
                Email:
                <span class="required_ast">
                    *
                </span>
            </p>
            <div class="secondary_panel_input_container">
                <input type="text" id="mail_email_input" class="secondary_panel_input secondary_panel_long_input pr re"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tbc">
        </div>
        <div class="secondary_panel_col1">
            <p class="secondary_panel_label">
                Your message:
                <span class="required_ast">
                    *
                </span>
            </p>
            <div class="secondary_panel_input_container">
                <textarea id="mail_message_input" class="secondary_panel_input secondary_panel_long_input pr"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tbc">
        </div>
        <a id="mail_submit" class="hover_button">Submit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I could just add some `max-height` css to clear up this problem. But that seems sloppy. I need to understand what's making it behave like this in the first place. Any ideas on what here could be making my `dialog()` act up? Thanks so much. [SITE](http://www2.iscotest.com/)

HTML for dialog
`<div id="upload_only_dialog" title="Upload a file without placing an order"> </div>`
JS for dialog

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("body").on("click", "#upload_only_trigger", function () {


        $("#upload_only_dialog").dialog({
            width: 380,
            height: 523,
            modal: true,
            position: 'center',
            closeOnEscape: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                //$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                //$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[image: very large titlebar...]